# Can I instantiate my Activity…and should I?

Tags: java, android

NEWBIE ALERT!

Here's the situation.  I've got an Android ListActivity class (AppWindow) that contains all the methods that create and update the UI for my application.  It includes a method (refreshWindow) that calls setListAdapter, and therefore must be non-static.  So far, I've been using a separate class (FileHandler) to perform manipulations on files that are referenced by the AppWindow class.  I've reached a point where I want to call the refreshWindow method when a certain file manipulation has been performed.  However, since the refreshWindow method is non-static, it seems that I would need to instantiate AppWindow and call the method through that instance.  However, I'm not sure how to do this or if it's even a good idea.  Perhaps I just need to move all of the FileHandler logic into AppWindow, although I'd prefer to keep them separate.

Here's a description of the situation in code form:

AppWindow.java

```
...

public class AppWindow extends ListActivity {

...

    void refreshWindow() {

    ...

    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter());

    ...

    }

...

}
```

FileHandler.java

```
...

class FileHandler extends Activity {

...

    static void doStuffToFiles() {

    ...

    AppWindow appWindow = new AppWindow();
    appWindow.refreshWindow();

    ...

    }

...

}
```

Should I be doing this?  If so, how do I properly instantiate AppWindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a static member variable; say act; in FileHandler
2. On creation of ListActivity set the variable act using 'this' variable of activity
3. Now you can access activity instance from FileHandler.

Comment: Perfect!  I put a static Context in FileHandler, set it to "this" from AppWindow as you suggested, then called ((AppWindow) context).refreshWindow().  Looks like it's gonna work!

Answer (score 0):

Update the UI must be in the UI thread. You can use handler to handle the message. The handler's constructor can contain the activity, so you can use it.